# New kind of identities?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, relations, universal-algebra, research

I found a new kind of identities which are half logic and half algebraic while working on a proof of NP-completeness.
They are like this:
$$
\frac{a+mb}{n+m} < \frac{a}{n} \iff      b < \frac{a}{n}
$$
It's the first time, I encounter such an identity.
It has the amusing and counter-intuitive property that the right member is not modified,
but the two left members are not algebraically equivalents.

Can you tell me if you ever encountereed such identities before?
These ones in particular? (There are 9 in total: equality, strict inequality or not, changing way if $n+m$ and $m$ have same sign or not.)
If not would you have suggestions for naming this kind of identities?

Moreover it would be interesting to know if there is a finite number of identities of this kind,
an infinite number but recursively enumerable, etc.

I do not ask for a proof [!] but only whether somebody knows
of a systematic treatment of equivalences of this kind in the
literature.

Feel free to search one but let me a few months to search by myself.
If I don't have any idea to prove it, I'll update my question to let you know anyone is welcome to publish on the subject.

Update 2013/07/26:

egreg definitely found the good idea behind these identities.
Let me update my question as follows :
Does there exist an identity of the type
$$
a ? b \iff a ? f(a,b)
$$
where f(a,b) is not a weighted mean of a and b (? may be =, <, >, <=, >=)?

Update 2013/07/30:

Thanks to zyx we now have a very simple way to construct an infinity of such identities. 
There remains a "few" questions:

Since it doesn't appear anyone know an article or a book that explicitely remarked these kind of identities as particular,
would you have suggestions for naming this kind of identities? (Question A)

Are all such identities as zyx described (in the meaning $(b-a)^n \times \dots$)? (Question B)
If not, are these identities recursively enumerable? (Question C)

What are the examples of such identities that are important, useful for demonstrating mathematical results? (Question D)
We already know that these identities from weigthed means are useful.
Do you have other examples from classical proofs? (Question D')

Note that the answer to question B is no if you change (or extend) the rules ;).
For example on rings instead of fields and if the inequality may be strict or not in the same identity.
As an example, if we take the ring $2\mathbb{Z}$ of even integers, we have the identity 
$$b < a \iff (b-a)^3 + 8 + a \leq a.$$

So far, I only had the following idea for naming this kind of identities: "semi-invariant identities". It shouldn't be hard to find a better name.

Update 2013/07/31 Clarification :

For now, I would like to answer the previous questions on fields only BUT the final word on these identities is out of reach.
Why?

The broader framework I see for these identities is the framework of universal algebras.
Given such an algebra $\mathcal{A}$ of domain $A$ and two binary relations $?_1$ and $?_2$ on $A$ such that $?_1$ and $?_2$ are orders or equivalence relations (yes, you can mix an equivalence relation and an order relation if you want but I have no idea if it could yield something interesting on some algebra), the idea is to study the identities that are as follows:

Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$, an $n$-$?_1$-$?_2$-semi-invariant identity on $\mathcal{A}$ is defined by three terms $f_1$, $f_2$, $f_3$ on $\mathcal{A}$ such that:
$$\forall (a_1, \dots, a_n) \in A^n, f_1(a_1, \dots, a_n) ?_1 f_2(a_1, \dots, a_n) \iff f_1(a_1, \dots, a_n) ?_2 f_3(a_1, \dots, a_n)$$
where $f_2$ and $f_3$ are not algebraically equivalents (as I noted in the original question).

Clearly, this is too broad to ask a question in this framework right now. These identities may be interesting on algebras used to construct graphs, etc. But not many people would see an interest in it or see what I'm talking about.
I would like to see what can be useful with these identities on the most standard algebras (fields is a good starting point) and it could benefit to many people not only a few dozens of specialists of some particular research domain.
Following part of zyx idea, one could go even further by considering arbitrary relations.

Comment: Are $m,n$ natural numbers?

Comment: I found the identities with m and n as natural numbers first but it is valid for reals also as long as you don't divide by zero. The identity with equality is valid on any field.

Comment: I think the proper naming and context for your problem is that of homomorphisms, and faithful homomorphisms, between structures with some relations.

Comment: I think homomorphisms, and faithful homomorphisms isn't the good naming and context (Please, have a look at my update). If you can explain why you consider it a good naming and context and if you still have this opinion after reading my update, please do explain your point of view.

Answer (score 7):

There is nothing too mysterious about this.  $$\frac{{a + mb}}{{n + m}} < \frac{a}{n} \Leftrightarrow a + mb < a + \frac{m}{n}a \Leftrightarrow mb < \frac{m}{n}a \Leftrightarrow b < \frac{1}{n}a \Leftrightarrow b < \frac{a}{n}$$

assuming $m,n>0$. For an insight, you're assuming that for each $m$, we have $$\frac{{mb + a}}{{n + m}} < \frac{a}{n}$$

as $m\to\infty$, the LHS goes to $b$. This means that $$b \leqslant \frac{a}{n}$$ But it cannot be the case $b=a/n$, because then we would get the absurdity $a<a$ from the original inequalirt. Of course, this is pushing things a little too much, since it this case we can easily manipulate the inequality. But maybe this interests you:

> **THM** Suppose that $x,y>0,a$ are such that, for each $n\geq 1$ $$a\leq x\leq a+\frac yn$$
>   Then $x\leq a$, that is $x=a$.

**P** Assume to the contrary that $x>a$. Then $x-a>0$. Then there exists $m$ such that $m(x-a)>y$, so $x-a>\dfrac ym$, that is $x>a+\frac ym$, contradicting our hypothesis.

Comment: I know the proof is trivial. You can write it directly like this (? may be < > or = as I said) : (a +mb)/(n+m) ? a/n <=> n(a+mb) ? (n+m)a <=> nmb ? ma <=> b ? a/n. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming $m,n>0$, if you set $c=a/n$, then the condition becomes

$$
\frac{mb+nc}{m+n}<c
\qquad\text{if and only if}\qquad
b<c.
$$

This shouldn't be surprising, because
$$
\frac{mb+nc}{m+n}
$$
is a weighted average of $b$ and $c$, so it lies between them.

Comment: Thanks I didn't see that. It makes it really clear.

Answer (score 1):

> update my question as follows : Does there exist an identity of the type
>   $$ a?b \iff a?f(a,b)$$
>   where $f(a,b)$ is not a weighted mean of a and b (? may be =, <, >, <=, >=)?

Sure.  Let $g(x,y)$ be a function that always has the same sign as $y$, and  $$f(a,b)= a + g(a,b-a).$$

All ?-preserving $f(a,b)$ can be constructed in that way.

---

(Edit, after the update with $f_1, f_2$ and $f_3$)

The generalization has similar solutions, on the same principle.  Suppose the relations $?_1$ and $?_2$ are equal.  For the question to be nontrivial one would need the set of $x$ for which $a?x$ holds, to have more than one element for some $a$.  But then we could take, for each $a$, any map $m(x)$ of this set to itself, and gather the maps into one function $M(a,x)$.  Our $x$ is a function ($f_2$) of $a$, so in fact we have a function $F(a)=M(a,f_2(a))$ such that $(\forall a) a ? f_2(a) \iff a?F(a)$ .

Allowing the two relations to be different loosens the problem further and now one can use $a$-dependent coordinate changes.  For example, in plane geometry, let $?_i$ be "is separated by distance at most $i$ from".  Then $a ?_1 f(a)$ if and only $a ?_2 g(a)$, where $g(a)$ is the point twice as far from $a$ as $b$, in the same direction.

The issue, that I think will be hard to remove while keeping the format of the identity, is that the idea of $aRb = aRc$ is simply "another solution" (of a condition satisfied for fixed $a$) and as far as that is true it leads to transformations of the solution space, which is a well explored theme.  It is a rich theme but not a new one.

The equation $aR_1 b = c R_2 a$, with $c$ determined from $b$, is similar to the concept of an *intertwiner*.  We could write $R_2$ in the opposite order by taking the opposite relation, and then it is close to what you wrote down in the generalized problem.

Comment: While this is indeed sufficient to find new examples of such identities with inequalities on $\mathbb{R}$, I fail to see why it is necessary. If you take a field without order ($\mathbb{F}_{31}$ for example) and search for all such identities with equalities, why should they satisfy $f(a,b)=a+g(a,b−a)$ where $g(a,0) = 0$ for any a. I fail to see why it can be a function g(a,b-a) instead of g(a,b) in any case. I may be missing some trivial argument.

Comment: Indeed you can always have b from a and b-a but still, your presentation suggests that it should be something like $(b-a)^n \times f(a,b)$. Eliminating such trivial cases, there may still be interesting examples. The idea is to find some kind of "kernel" of such identities. How they can be constructed, classified, etc.

Comment: It is necessary and sufficient for faithful preservation of all the relations at once, which is equivalent to f.p. of equality and either of the inequalities.  For f.p. of equality only, a necessary and sufficient condition is the same expression but with $g(x,y)$ equal to zero if and only if $y=0$.  For inequality alone, I haven't thought about it, but it may be equivalent to what I wrote under a continuity assumption.  In each case, setting $G(p,q) = f(p,q+p) - p$ translates between one form and the other.

Comment: Thanks but try to go further than trivial answers. I didn't asked for faithful preservation of all relations at once. I was saying in my original question "changing way if n+m and m have same sign or not" that reversing the inequality would still be considered as an exemple of this kind of inequalities. I didn't repeated this for simplicity in the update. Moreover the true question is "what did you mean by $g(a,b-a)$?". Since $f(a,b) =  a + f(a,b) -a = a + g'(a,b) = a + g(a,b-a)$ is always true for some $g$, we need to know how to construct $g$. I updated my question to explicit the questions.

Comment: By g' I didn't mean the derivative of g, read h(a,b) instead.

Comment: How to construct $g$ is not such an interesting question, or at least a totally separable question, since this answer shows that there is a huge freedom to let $g$ be whatever you want, subject to a very easily satisfied condition relating $y$ and $g(x,y)$, and still have a solution to the updated (07/26) problem.  If you impose additional axioms you can get interesting classes such as weighted means or nonlinear means or  diffeomorphisms.  But the general thing is too broad because your condition does not tie different values of $a$ together, and one can solve each $a$ independently.

Comment: I know the general thing is too broad. I'll update my question to explain what is the broader framework to study this kind of identities in my point of view. I didn't specified it but the identity should be valid for any element a in the studied algebra, otherwise it wouldn't have much interest. Constructing g is an interesting question if you prune the trivial constructs and there is still some non-trivial construction you can exhibit.

Comment: Sorry I used $f_1$, etc. but I really mean terms and not arbitrary functions. It does mean you have to construct a finite term using the operations of the algebra only. I don't see why you can simplify $f_1(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ to $a$ in any algebra. I don't have a counter example in mind right now but I doubt you can do it. Maybe it is true you can simplify if all operations of the algebra have an inverse operation. This could be a theorem in the study of these identities. See next comment.

Comment: I see that your argument works partly on finite fields because you can write en arbitrary map $m(x)$ as a term (example on $\mathbb{F}_3$: $$(x-a_2)(x-a_3)[(a_1-a_2)(a_1-a_3)]^{-1}\times m(a_1) + (x-a_1)(x-a_3)[(a_2-a_1)(a_2-a_3)]^{-1}\times m(a_2) + (x-a_1)(x-a_2)[(a_3-a_1)(a_3-a_2)]^{-1}\times m(a_3).$$ I used $a_1, a_2, a_3$ to make more apparent the general construction.)

Comment: I'll think carefully about the rest of your answer and will probably add more comments later. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not knowing the language of universal algebra, I interpreted $f_i$ as functions.   Some of these "take the other solution" operations can be done using only the algebra operations, such as taking the second root of a quadratic equation, and then you get automorphisms of the structure.

Comment: >"Our x is a function (f2) of a" that's just false.

Comment: It is trivially true given the assumptions of that argument: $a$ is a notation for an n-tuple $(a_1, ..., a_n)$,  $f_1(a)=a$ is the identity map, $f_2$ is a function, and $x$ is $f_2$.

Comment: It has no sense at all, a must be an element of the domain of the algebra. The relations $?_1$ and $?_2$ are binary! They don't apply to two n-tuples.

Comment: Concerning the third paragraph of your update, this is an interesting point of view when $?_1$ = $?_2$ and indeed between $b$ and the weighted mean of $a$ and $b$ there is an algebraic transform of the solution space for a given $a$. Note that my definition could yield some transforms of the solution space that can not be expressed by an algebraic term. Note also that when you have to keep $f_1(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ instead of $a$, the transform is valid for only a limited subset of the domain of the algebra.

Comment: If you can provide what you think are the most appropriate references, I'll try to find the pdfs if available. I don't know if transforms of the solution space has already been studied with this point of view.

Comment: Concerning the last paragraph of your update, please expand on the similarity with intertwiners.

Comment: > "Some of these "take the other solution" operations can be done using only the algebra operations, such as taking the second root of a quadratic equation, and then you get automorphisms of the structure." Sorry but it sounds like bullshit. The square root is not among the operations I would allow in any field. Moreover there is no first and second root of a quadratic equation. There is two roots but first or second is arbitrary and has no mathematical meaning. Moreover a quadratic equation on the reals can have both roots as complex numbers, etc.

Comment: "Taking the other root" means compute another root from a given one, not solve the equation from coefficients.

Comment: The $f$ in an equation $f \circ g = h \circ f$ is said to intertwine the action of $g$ and $h$.  This is used as an explicit term usually in representation theory where one $f$ intertwines a collection of $g$'s and $h$'s defining the action of objects $G$ and $H$, such as groups.

Comment: I modified my profile to use my real name instead of the display name user87707 that was created with my account. You can see a photo of me on my website I added to my profile some time ago. Please do add your real name and if possible provide a picture of you.

Comment: >""Taking the other root" means compute another root from a given one, not solve the equation from coefficients." Give an example I'm curious to see that.

Comment: For example, in a quadratic equation $x^2 -px + q = 0$, the roots sum to $p$, so $t \to p-t$ constructs "the other root", and more important for present discussion, is an automorphism of the equation.  Well, OK, we knew the parabola has an axis of symmetry.  But this is less trivial when you consider quadratic forms (hypersurfaces) in several variables, where the "take other root" operations generate symmetry groups of the h.surface.

Comment: And in Galois theory (which is all about transformations of solution spaces) there is the idea of a normal extension, where from one root, there are rational function that generate all the other roots.

Comment: While interesting, many ideas you suggest don't fit in the framework of these identities. I'll extend on that since implicitely you define other new kind of identities.

Comment: > "$f1(a)=a$ is the identity map" You consider a function from elements of an algebra to n-tuples over the algebra, it can't be a term of this algebra.

Comment: >"a quadratic equation $x^2−px+q=0$" at least it wasn't the joke: If the discriminant is zero you can compute the second root from the first ><. Note that you have to use part of the coefficients of the equation to compute the other root. As far as I see a generalization of your idea here is as follows: you have a function $f_1$ from $\mathbb{F}^n$ to some set $E$ of equations on $\mathbb{F}$, a relation $?_1 = ?_2$ on $E\times \mathbb{F}$ meaning $x$ is a solution of the equation and you have $f_2, f_3$ from $\mathbb{F}^n$ to $\mathbb{F}$. Clearly, it doesnt fit in my framework.

Comment: >"The $f$ in an equation $f∘g=h∘f$ is said to intertwine the action of g and h." Again it doesnt fit in my framework $\circ$ is an operation on an algebra of functions. You can generalize your idea to another kind of identities as follows: given an algebra, $\circ_1$, $\circ_2$ two binary operations of this algebra and $?_3$ a binary relation over the domain of the algebra, you search terms $f_1,f_2,f_3$ such that $$f_1(a_1,\dots,a_n) \circ_1 f_2(a_1,\dots,a_n) ?_3 f_1(a_1,\dots,a_n) \circ_2 f_3(a_1,\dots,a_n)$$. It's an interesting idea but you should open a new question for it.

Comment: So right now we have three kinds of identities that can be further generalized if we remove the binary restrictions on $?_i$ and $\circ_i$ (I don't want to study these generalizations right now, the writings of such would be a real mess).

Comment: Note that for the second kind of identities I'm mixing coefficients and "solution variables": $f_1(p,q,r) = x^2 -px + q$, $f_2(p,q,r) = r$, $f_3(p,q,r) = p-r$.

Comment: My bad, the second kind of identities does fit in the first.  I realized my mistake today. I was focused on the ways to reduce $f_1(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ to some variable $a$ on the domain and didn't saw it was not always possible ; trivially because sometimes you can reduce it to a constant of the domain. So it appears that solutions of equations is a "degenerated case" where $f_1 = 0$. And in standard cases where you have subtraction and consider $?_1 = ?_2$ both orders or equality, all these identities can be reduced to this degenerated case.

Comment: It raises an interesting question : what should be considered the canonical representation of such identities ? Writing the weighted mean: $$\frac{na+mb}{m+n} - a < 0 \iff b - a < 0$$ doesn't look good.